How to Adjust Row Heights in PrimeNG's p-table, Specifically for p-columnFilter Rows?
I am working on a PrimeNG p-table component where I want to ensure that the height of the row containing the p-columnFilter components matches the height of the header row and the "Search keyword" input row. However, I am having trouble achieving this, and I'm not sure what the best approach is for styling these elements consistently.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
<p-table
  #dt1
  [value]="products"
  styleClass="p-datatable-striped p-datatable-sm"
  [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem', cursor: 'pointer' }"
  selectionMode="single"
  [loading]="loading"
  [scrollable]="true"
  scrollHeight="calc(100vh - 85px)"
  [resizableColumns]="true"
  [globalFilterFields]="[
    'departement',
    'rayon',
    'metaFamille',
    'famille',
    'produit',
    'sku',
    'libelle',
    'couleur',
    'taille'
  ]"
  [(selection)]="selectedStore"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <p-iconField iconPosition="left">
      <p-inputIcon>
        <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
      </p-inputIcon>
      <input
        pInputText
        type="text"
        (input)="dt1.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value, 'contains')"
        placeholder="Search keyword"
        style="height: 20px"
      />
    </p-iconField>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th pResizableColumn>Département</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>Rayon</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>Méta famille</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>Famille</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>PRODUIT</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>SKU</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>LIBELLE</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>COULEUR</th>
      <th pResizableColumn>TAILLE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="departement"
          placeholder="Search by Département"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="rayon"
          placeholder="Search by Rayon"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="metaFamille"
          placeholder="Search by MF"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="famille"
          placeholder="Search by Famille"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="produit"
          placeholder="Search by produit"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="sku"
          placeholder="Search by SKU"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="libelle"
          placeholder="Search by Libelle"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="couleur"
          placeholder="Search by Couleur"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
      <th>
        <p-columnFilter
          type="text"
          field="taille"
          placeholder="Search by Taille"
          ariaLabel="Filter Name"
        />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
    <tr
      [pSelectableRow]="product"
      (click)="showDetails(product)"
      style="font-size: 0.8rem"
    >
      <td>{{ product.departement }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.rayon }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.metaFamille }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.famille }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.produit }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.sku }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.libelle }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.couleur }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.taille }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="9">Aucunes données</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="sidebarVisible" position="right">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <span>{{ selectedProduct.libelle }}</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-sidebar>


enter image description here
I've tried various CSS approaches, but none seem to consistently align the heights of these rows. Here's what I've attempted:
Applying height and line-height styles directly to the elements.
Using classes like .p-datatable-thead to target the header, and .p-column-filter for the filters.
Using !important to force the styles, but still no luck.
Additionally, I'm unsure if any of the default PrimeNG styling classes (e.g., .p-datatable-header, .p-column-filter) should be involved in solving this problem.
Could someone guide me on how to properly align these rows' heights? Also, what is the recommended approach for styling such elements in PrimeNG in a consistent and maintainable way?
Thank you for your help!

I wonder if this has a connection?  https://primeng.org/table#styling
